# Cannot send email with Wakanda Server 1.1.3

Tags: email, server, wakanda

When I attempt to send an email via Wakanda Server, using the following code, an error occurs:

```
var mail = require('waf-mail/mail');
var message = new mail.Mail();
message.subject = "Here the subject of the email";
message.from = "me@mydomain.com";
message.to = 'user@somedomain.com';
message.setBody("This is a test message");

mail.send({
    address: 'mail.mydomain.com',
    port: 587,
    isSSL: true,
    username: 'MY-USERNAME',
    password: 'MY-PASSWORD',
    domain: 'mydomain.com'
}, message);
```

When running in debug mode, during `mail.send` the error occurs at the following line:

```
socket = tls.connect(port, address, connectCallback);
```

When debugging, I cannot step into this function call and the error occurs when attempting to do so.

The docs say that `mail.send` should return a status object, but that doesn't happen here. Adding a try/catch to the `mail.send` call produces this Error object in the catch:

```
Error = {
    error: [{
        componentSignature: "xbox"
        errCode: 5
        message: ""}],
    messages: [""]
}
```

Wakanda Server 1.1.3

MacOS 10.11.6

I am **not** using gmail to send the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct *address* and *port* in the mail.send properties.
you have to search the correct  smtp settings for the mail you are using.
for gmail i succed sending emails using the following :

```
var mail = require('waf-mail/mail'); 
var message = new mail.Mail();
message.subject = "Test";
message.from = "me@gmail.com";
message.to = ['me@gmail.com' , 'user@wakanda.io'];
message.setBody("This is a test message");
mail.send({
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    port: 465,
    isSSL: true,
    username: 'username', 
    password: 'password', 
    domain: 'gmail.com'
}, message);
```

Comment: It turns out that the last character of the password was missing. Not sure how that happened. Even so, waf-mail should return the status object with an action property value of 3 (authentication failed) instead of throwing an incomprehensible exception.